# png_read_info identfier not found

Tags: c++, libpng

I'm trying to read a PNG using the libpng library on Windows 64 bit.

When calling the png_read_info function, Visual Studio 2010 gives the following error:

```
'png_read_info': identifier not found
```

This is the only method that gives errors, all other libpng structures and method calls work as expected.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Apparently I had to include a header named pnglibconf.h, which I found in the scripts directory located in my libpng directory as "pnglibconf.h.prebuilt". I copied the file in the main libpng directory (which is the include directory) and removed the prebuilt tag. This managed to solve the identifier problem.

Comment: Is this a Cxxxx or a Lxxxx error? Do you have any idea about the version of the libpng?

Comment: Posted solution above

Comment: pnglibconf.h is new with libpng version 1.5.0.  We'll mention that in the libpng INSTALL file.

Comment: How did you build libpng?  The makefiles, configure, and project scripts should have created pnglibconf.h for you.

Comment: Thanks, could this also cause the next error I'm facing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564718/libpng-error-png-unsigned-integer-out-of-range

Comment: I built libpng through CMake using the Visual Studio Windows64 bit compiler and using the latest libpng release found on the website.

Comment: I see now! The header was thrown in the build directory I specified when using CMake, instead of being thrown into the include directory, which is the main libpng directory.