# libpng error: PNG unsigned integer out of range

Tags: c++, libpng

When trying to read a PNG from memory I came across this funky error:

```
libpng error:: PNG unsigned integer out of range
```

This error is caused by

```
png_read_info(png_ptr,info_ptr);
```

Which uses following handler:

```
static void ReadDataFromBuffer(png_structp png_ptr, png_bytep outBytes,
    png_size_t byteCountToRead){
        PNGDataPtr dataptr=(PNGDataPtr)png_get_io_ptr(png_ptr);
        png_uint_32 i;
        cout<<byteCountToRead<<endl;
        cout<<&outBytes<<endl;
        cout<<dataptr->len<<endl;
        cout<<dataptr->p<<endl;

        if(byteCountToRead>dataptr->len){
            png_error(png_ptr,"EOF");
            return;
        }

        for(i=0;i<byteCountToRead;i++){

            outBytes[i]=dataptr->p[i];
        }
        dataptr->p+=byteCountToRead;
        dataptr->len-=byteCountToRead;
        png_uint_32 a = png_get_uint_32(outBytes);
        cout<<a<<" "<<PNG_UINT_31_MAX<<endl;

}
```

Through some intensive searching I found that the error gets called by the following code in
pgnrutil.c:

```
png_uint_32 /* PRIVATE */
png_get_uint_31(png_structp png_ptr, png_bytep buf)
{
    png_uint_32 i = png_get_uint_32(buf);
    if (i > PNG_UINT_31_MAX)
    png_error(png_ptr, "PNG unsigned integer out of range.\n");
    return (i);
}
```

So I checked the value of png_get_uint_32(outBytes) and it was indeed higher than PNG_UINT_31_MAX, 230374511 to be exact.

How do I fix this?

Edit:

Some clarification on the PNGDataPtr:

```
typedef struct{
    png_bytep p;
    png_uint_32 len;
} PNGData,*PNGDataPtr;
```

When calling

```
png_set_read_fn(png_ptr,(png_voidp) &pngdata, ReadDataFromBuffer);
```

pngdata represents a PNGData object, which has a pointer to my databuffer which contains the entire PNG in memory, and len contains the size of the entire PNG, which is between 40 and 80KB

Edit: Here's a link to a png I get when I use fwrite to save the received databuffer: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m5enp9jljglhs5c/test.png

Comment: Can you include a link to the actual PNG? Perhaps it's not a valid PNG...

Comment: The Actual PNG is never actually saved. It's a depth matrix compressed into a png in memory,  then sent through a network. I'm now trying to decode the png so I can access my depth matrix again. 

This may sound wonky, but when I save the received databuffer with fwrite as a png file instead of decoding it in memory, I can open it and watch the png which represents a correct depth matrix (people and objects can be identified).

The databuffer is represented by a char array (char *), could this cause a problem?

Comment: Updated OP with some more info

Answer (score 6):

Previously I wrote:
You've probably got your endian condition mixed up...

EDIT:
You are reading the PNG signature when you should have skipped past the first 8 bytes.  Your report has a typo: the number is actually 2303741511 (you omitted a "1" from your question) which is the byte string "\211 P N G"

A workaround for this problem in your code is to use

```
png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr,0)
```

to inform libpng that your data pointer is pointing to the beginning of the 8-byte signature and the reader needs to skip them.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how would I go and try to fix this? I'm a big of a newb.

Comment: Couldn't I just use the htonl and ntohl functions seeing as I'm sending the png's over a network?

Comment: Sure.  But only convert the multi-byte integers, not the pixel bytes and other single-byte things, whether you're sending them over a network or just writing a file.  Any multi-byte integers in the datastream have to be in network byte order.

Comment: But the depth values are between 0 and 5000, hence the PNG has been set as 16bit. Wouldn't this mean that I'd have to use the functions on the pixel bytes as well? And isn't it strange that using fwrite on the raw databuffer on the server side produces the exact same png as on the client side, even without the hotnl and ntohl functions?

Sorry for the ignorance btw, my experience on this subject is rather limited.

Comment: Yes, 16-bit color and alpha samples also need to be most-significant-byte first.  Fread/fwrite work on bytes so they don't care about the byte order.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks for the explanation. I'm currently unable to access my server but I will try to implement your advice tomorrow