# Java image cropping breaks PNG for libpng

Tags: java, c++, windows, image-processing, libpng

So currently I'm using `C++` code to dump screenshots to the disk. I read them in using `Java` in order to crop them and then I write them back to the disk so `C++` can load them back in and apply image algorithms ([`OpenCV`](https://opencv.org)).

After writing the modified image back from `Java`, I however get the following error in `C++`:

```
libpng error: PNG unsigned integer out of range
```

My cropping code in `Java` is [as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23585894/3764804):

```
private void cropImage(Path imageFilePath) throws IOException
{
    File imageFile = imageFilePath.toFile();
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    BufferedImage subImage = bufferedImage.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
    BufferedImage copiedImage = new BufferedImage(subImage.getWidth(), subImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics graphics = copiedImage.createGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(subImage, 0, 0, null);
    ImageIO.write(copiedImage, getExtension(imageFile.getName()), imageFile);
}
```

Surprisingly, if I view the cropped `PNG` it looks fine in the `Windows Photo` app but will not work in `libpng`. Without the cropping step, there's no `libpng` issue. Is there anything wrong with my `PNG` cropping code?

Comment: Why hop through all those hoops and not crop the image in OpenCV, then proceed from the cropped image?

Comment: As it works in other applications, perhaps the problem is your C++ code that uses libPNG? Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22564718/1428606

Comment: @RealSkeptic: When I use `OpenCV` image processing in C++ instead I don't run into this error :)